# Connect to SQL Server database error

Tags: c#, sql-server, web-services, database-connection

I have my own server. This server has an address `myserverdns.ddns.net`.

I created a C# web service NOT on my server, I'm developing this WS on my personal computer.

I give you all the informations I have:

- Server address: **myserverdns.ddns.net** (example)
- Server remote desktop port: **33**
- I created a Server istance named **PIERDEMOSERVER**
- My db is named: **TestApp_DB**
- I unlocked **1433 port** for incoming connections
- I enabled TCP/IP on my server
- I created the rule on firewall
- I turned off firewall
- My user is **Server** (example)
- My password is **password** (example)

I tryed on my c# webservice to **add server connection**

- Data origin: *Microsof SQL Server (SqlClient)*
- Server name: *myserverdns.ddns.net\PIERDEMOSERVER*

I always got **error 26** or **error 40**

In my webservice I wrote a Db using *Entity framework Code First*, and I want to push up my code to this

NOTE: My Webservice will be published on the same server of the SQL Database.

How can I connect this db to my WS? I'm stuck here from 3 days..

Thanks all, I tryed to give you all informations, if something more is needed tell me

**PS:**

*Don't link me all the questions where they explain how to set up TCP/IP or where they say to add the rule on firewall.. I've already done it, thanks*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've created a firewall opening based on Port.

You may need to do it "by application".

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1929/configure-windows-firewall-to-work-with-sql-server/

***Using firewall with SQL Server on dynamic ports***
If you have configured SQL Server to listen on dynamic ports, even then you can use the firewall for your SQL Server instance. To do this you include the "sqlservr.exe" program in your firewall exception list. Just go to exceptions tab and click on 'Add Program' button.

PS

Just because you "did it already", there may have been something you missed.

APPEND

So try a cheap trick.....just to isolate machine connectivity vs code-issues.

Go to your "client" machine, Control-Panel/Admin Tools/ DSN(ODBC).

Create a temporary machine DSN to the sql server.   (You can delete it later).

This will isolate the issue "from code"........report back the result, the result will give better guidance to up which tree to bark.

APPEND

Go here and get "PortQryUI"

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24009

and get this tool.

This will let you ping the server....and see if you can get to it at that basic level.

THEN

Go here

http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Find

"Connect via an IP address"

"Connect via an IP address" is the MOST specific connection string you can define.
(Note, if you're not using sql authentication, then you'll need to change UserID and Password for Trusted_Connection credentials)

It has the IP address, the Port, and the Network Library.

If your DSN test doesn't work, and this "very specific" connection string does not work.....then you've got an issue that means going back through the tutorials (that you said not to post) and go through every detail.

If the DSN test doesn't work, your code will never work.  Which again, means going back through the detailed servers.

If PortQryUI doesn't work, then you have a more basic connection issue that is outside of sql server.

Comment: you right, it's because usually people flag as duplicate without even reading the post, i wanted to prevent it :)  Anyway I tryed this way but still error 26-40

Comment: I don't know if I did it correctly, I went where you posted, set up a new SQL server connection to my private SQL server. I have this error: "SQL Server Error: 17 [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]Not existing Server SQL or denied access.

Comment: Right.  So its not your "code".  Its a more general error.  I would suggest trying to set up the DSN .. and use the client_options of TCP instead of named pipes.

Comment: thanks a lot, I will try. You got a link or some guideline on how to do it?

Comment: I just re-read where you say "no tcp".. Why is that?  I'm having a flashback to a client-site visit where their db would not connect (w named pipes) .. we ffinally figured out the magic registry settings for tcp.  Keep in mind this wsa early 2000's.   No tutorial for the DSN...just fish around while you're going through the wizard.  Again, the DSN is just a cheap trick way to test different options..and to eliminate your code as the issue.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it in a while. I try first in the server side and after in the client side if it works. thanks :)

Comment: I tryed all of those but nothing, I still can't connect to my server :(

Comment: I added some APPENDs to my answer.  If those don't help, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Doing the workaround you suggested i'm having "SQL Server not existing or denied access" (error 17). I have to write "myserverdns.ddns.net\MYSERVER"?

Comment: oh wait new edit, i check it! thanks for all your help

Comment: You are my idol. the portquery tool you linked showed my 1433 port is "filtered". This pointed me to the network admin, he closed all ports with firewall. so I was pointing to a port which was open in the machine but closed in the router. one week lost for this. Thanks really a lot! You saved me

Comment: Cool.  Yep, PortQueryUI is in my "must have" bag of tricks for connection issues.  Now go clean up those temp DSN's.

Comment: Yes thanks a lot again! a little question: i'm using noip and I have "myserverdns.ddns.net". can I use it as ip in connection string?

Comment: Probably.  But not sure.